# Как заменить любое значение атрибута

Tags: jquery

Есть у меня `input`:
`<input type="hidden" class="inputtext" data-lang="house"></input>`

Есть `img`:
`<img class="house" src="">`

В зависимости от языка в `input` вставляется ссылка текстом(например `images/img_1.png`). Через `jQuery` я беру эту ссылку и ставлю в `src` `img`.
При загрузке все работает корректно, но вот когда я пытаюсь уже вручную изменить, почему то накладываются значения. В `replace` я использую пустую строку и меняю на значение переменной. Видать когда строка уже не пустая оно срабатывает некорректно:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgLink = $('input.inputtext').text();
  $(document).find('img.house').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('', imgLink));
  });

  $(".langswtch").click(function() {
      $(document).find('img.house').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('', imgLink));
      });
  });
});
```

Если ли какой то способ, который позволяет заменить любое старое значение на новое?
Надеюсь понятно вопрос сформулировал.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так? :

```js
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
    $input = $('.input').val(),
    $img = $('.img');

  $img.attr('src', $input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="btn">загрузить</a>
<input type="text" class="input">



<img src="" alt="" class="img">
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое! Единственное, почему то нужно 2 раза на нажать на кнопку, потом уже картинка меняется.